# Converting aggregate initialization of a struct containing a CONST char array[N] member into a constructor

Tags: c++, c++14

Given a simple struct containing a **const** char array, this can be easily initialized via aggregate initialization:

```
struct int_and_text {
  constexpr static int Size = 8;
  const int i;
  const char text[Size];
};
const int_and_text some_data[] = { { 0, "abc"}, { 77,  "length8" } };
```

But now I want to add a constructor, but so far nothing I tried worked, even one using a `constexpr memcpy-ish` variant.

```
template <std::size_t N>
int_and_text(int i_, const char (&text_)[N]) 
  : i{i_}, 
   text{"  ?  " /* const text[8] from const text[1-8] */ }
  { static_assert(N <= Size); }
```

Is this possible? A `const char text_[8]` constructor argument seems to decay into a `char*`. In the long term making everything `constexpr` would be nice as well.

Comment: In C++, use `std::array` instead.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::string` for strings?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: `string` heap allocates (SSO nonwithstanding) and is bad for C compatibility

Comment: "Bad for C compatibility" is a structure with constructors or other member functions as well. You can't really pass such a structure to a C function.

Comment: @finitegraygreen Why do you think it doesn't work? `std::array<char, 6> a = {"hello"};` this one works.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5b038a32786b9fb1

Comment: @liliscent: Sorry, my mistake. I omitted the braces. printf/iostream still do not like it though and it would have to provide a .c_str() or equivalent. I could `reinterpret_cast` such a struct though (ugly...) because @Someprogrammerdude the memory layout is the same, static members or methods do not matter.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: nice, thanks. could you turn this into a full answer? Also works with c++14. I'll have to read up on `index_sequence`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>

class int_and_text
{
public:    
    template <std::size_t N>
    int_and_text(int i_, const char (&text_)[N]) 
        : int_and_text(i_, text_, std::make_index_sequence<N>{})
    {
    }

private:
    template <std::size_t N, std::size_t... Is>
    int_and_text(int i_, const char (&text_)[N], std::index_sequence<Is...>) 
        : i{i_}
        , text{text_[Is]...}
    {
        static_assert(N <= Size);
    }

    constexpr static int Size = 8;
    const int i;
    const char text[Size];
};

const int_and_text some_data[] = { {0, "abc"}, {77, "length8"} };
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0e2ead8b099778f)